# Build URL/URI with 3 pieces (scheme, baseurl and suffix url) of information

Tags: java, java-8

I have 3 pieces of information that form a url/uri.

```
String myscheme = "https";
String basePath = "www.theothercompany.com";
String suffixPath = "/api/v1/things";
```

How do I "compose" a full URI or URL with (only) the three things above.

I've been through several constructors for :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html
and
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

like I tried this:

```
   URI x = new URI(myscheme , basePath , suffixPath);
```

or

```
   URI y = new URI(myscheme , basePath , suffixPath, "");
```

But I keep getting things like

httpswww.theothercompany.comapi/v1/things

obviously, removing "parts" like "://" and "/".

I don't have a port, or a ssp or a user or textfile...or other things I saw in the constructors of the 2 above oracle links.

I can't believe this is roadblocking me !!

Below are some other (already) pulled in packages.  I do not want to add another one (like org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder for example).....to bloat the dependencies.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
```

and

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux', version: springBootVersion

compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: commonsLangVersion

compile 'org.projectreactor:reactor-spring:1.0.1.RELEASE'
```

APPEND

Ok, as per suggested, I fixed my mislabelling of the 3 parts.

```
   String myScheme = "https";
    String myHost = "www.theothercompany.com";
    String myPath = "/api/v1/things";

    java.net.URL computedFullUrl = null;
    String urlToStringValue = "";
    String urlToExternalFormValue = "";
    String urlToUriStringValue = "";
    try {

        /* this works....or does not exception out */
        computedFullUrl = new java.net.URL(myScheme, myHost, myPath);

        if (null != computedFullUrl) {
            urlToStringValue = computedFullUrl.toString();
            urlToExternalFormValue = computedFullUrl.toExternalForm();
            urlToUriStringValue = computedFullUrl.toURI().toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //throw new RuntimeException((ex));
        // temporary swallow
        String temp = ex.getMessage();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So the above works.

I get (all three "convert back to a full string" values of) :

```
https://www.theothercompany.com/api/v1/things
```

I finally figured it out.

It had nothing to do with URI or URL.

When i read the values from a property file, the beginning "/" was being stripped from "/api/v1/things"

The value in the string was "api/v1/things". (no quotes of course).  That was my issue.

I'll leave the question up so others can learn from my faux pas.

Gaaaaaa.

Comment: As far as I tried, it seems that `java.net.URL`'s three parameter constructor `URL(String,String,String)` gave me a result exactly what you wanted, give it a try.

Comment: MNEMO.  Now I understand.  You are right  BUT I didn't mention the last part.  (was very tired and frustrated when I wrote the question)  How do I get a URL back a a "full string"?  that is what broke it...  i tried  myURL.toString() and that jams the overall full string.  (I need use the full-string for a rest call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is partially caused by not using the correct technical terms:

- `www.theothercompany.com` is a **host name**, not a “basePath”.
- `/api/v1/things` is the **path**, not a “suffixPath”

Obviously, you want to construct a *hierarchical* URI, but [one of the constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29) you use, is designed to construct an *opaque* URI¹, expecting the arguments `scheme`, `ssp` (scheme specific part), and `fragment`.

The [constructor’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29) precisely describes the outcome:

> This constructor first builds a URI in string form using the given components as follows:
>
> 1. Initially, the result string is empty.
> 2. If a scheme is given then it is appended to the result, followed by a colon character (`':'`).
> 3. If a scheme-specific part is given then it is appended. Any character that is not [a legal URI character](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#legal-chars) is [quoted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#quote).
> 4. Finally, if a fragment is given then a hash character (`'#'`) is appended to the string, followed by the fragment. Any character that is not a legal URI character is quoted.

leading to `https:www.theothercompany.com#/api/v1/things`.

Since you want to construct a hierarchical URI composed of `scheme`, `host`, and `path`, [the second constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) is the right one:

> `public URI​(String scheme, String host, String path, String fragment)`
>
> Constructs a hierarchical URI from the given components.

So using `new URI(myscheme , basePath , suffixPath, "")` leads to `https://www.theothercompany.com/api/v1/things#`.

When you change it to `new URI(myscheme , basePath , suffixPath, null)`, you’ll get `https://www.theothercompany.com/api/v1/things`.

This demonstrates why named factories are preferable over overloaded constructors, as such a semantic difference between two constructors only differing by one parameter, is not very intuitive.

---

¹ or to construct a hierarchical URI by specifying the syntactical elements manually, which is rarely needed

Comment: I actually have them identified correctly (scheme, host, path) in my application.properties.  The unintentional rewording..was me hacking together a "reproducible example" for SOF (as per guidelines).and being tired at the end of the day.  I'm working through the suggestions.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer to complete the question.  i finally figured it out.    When i read the values from a property file, the beginning "/" was being stripped from "/api/v1/things"         I updated my question.       That was how the / was disappearing, not the URL or URI.  Couldn't see the simplest thing because of frustration.  Thanks for input.